# Weighted summing time associated data for univariate model?

Tags: regression, bioinformatics, univariate

I have a situation where I have several mice A, B, C, etc., each of which has several thousand datapoints, all associated with a timepoint of 1 year, in addition to a single datapoint associated with earlier timepoints. I'd like to identify which of these 1 year datapoints is most significant. So something like

```
Mouse 1: M1_val, M2_val, M3_val, M4_val, M5_val, M6_val, Y1_val_1, 
..., Y1_val_100000
```

I'm currently just using a univariate model trying to find which datapoints in the 1 year set best predict the singular 6 month value of each mouse. But it feels like a waste to not use the other datapoints for the mice. Is there some way that I can weight the datapoints, months 1 through 6, resulting in a single value which is then related to the large 1 year dataset? Specifically I'm asking how I should go about determining the weights for the time points